# alter array of object value base on dynamic property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have array of object like this

```
let arr = [
  {
    "james-0": {
      "value": "",
      "error": false
    },
    "john-0": {
      "value": "",
      "error": false
    },
    "jordan-0": {
      "value": "",
      "error": false
    }
  }
]
```

**I want to alter error to true if the value is not false / empty string.**

I tried this but it deosn't seem to work, I can't hardcode `james-${i}`

```
arr = arr.map((o,i) => {

  let prop = o[`james-${i}`]
  if(!prop.value) prop.error = true

  console.log(prop)

  return {
    ...o,
    [`james-${i}`]: prop
  }
})
```

Comment: have you tried `reduce`?

Comment: @user3106579 I have no way but to hardcode john, james and jordan even with `reduce`

Comment: there is only one element in your array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply that ?

```js
let arr = 
    [ { "james-0":  { "value": "",    "error": false } 
      , "john-0":   { "value": "abc", "error": false } 
      , "jordan-0": { "value": "",    "error": false } 
      } 
    ] 

Object.keys(arr[0]).forEach( e=> arr[0][e].error = ( arr[0][e].value == ''))

console.log( arr )
```

Comment: Error should be true when the value is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "james-0": {
      "value": "",
      "error": false
    },
    "john-1": {
      "value": "",
      "error": false
    },
    "jordan-2": {
      "value": "val",
      "error": false
    }
  }
];

arr = arr.map(value => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
     if (!value[key].value) {
           value[key].error = true;
        }
    })
    return value;
})

console.log(arr);
```

.